# Is there any way to decrease the time it takes for a pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect to occur?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm using a 3-node MongoDB replica set and connecting to it using Pymongo v3.3.1.

In testing the handling of errors like AutoReconnect and ServerSelectionTimeout and such I find that I can't (safely/reliably) control how long it takes to raise an AutoReconnect exception.

If I instantiate MongoClient with the argument `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` set to, for instance, 2000, I **do** see the ServerSelectionTimeout exceptions return in about 2 seconds. However, when the conditions are just right to trigger an AutoReconnect it always takes at least 20 seconds, sometime closer to 30 seconds!

How can I constrain this behavior? I'm shooting for relatively high availability and want to detect network/replica set anomalies and commence my retry logic rather rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, after some tinkering, that using the MongoClient argument `socketTimeoutMS`, if set to something quicker than that observed by AutoReconnect, will supersede AutoReconnect.

Contrary to my initial concern, this does not interfere with long running queries as the socket connected just fine.

I discovered that after the first NetworkTimeout exception is raised as a result of this setting it can take 10 seconds or so to attempt again. That is solved by also passing the `connectTimeoutMS` argument to MongoClient with, most likely, the same value as that of `socketTimeoutMS`.

Please post a response here if anyone discovers any caveats to this solution.